# Count all values from Column A but only certain values from Column B

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, sum

**(1) Table ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4316410/2)):**

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Product Text,
    Sales_Monetary VARCHAR(255),
    Returns_Monetary VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Sales
(Product, Sales_Monetary, Returns_Monetary)
VALUES 
("Product A", "500", "300"),
("Product A", "200", "130"),
("Product A", "600", "0"),
("Product A", "900", "540"),
("Product B", "150", "70"),
("Product B", "480", "0"),
("Product B", "220", "0"),
("Product B", "300", "0"),
("Product B", "890", "670"),
("Product C", "360", "0"),
("Product C", "740", "530");
```

**(2) Desired Result:**

```
            Sold_Items   Returned_Items    Return_Rate_Items
Product A      4            3                  0.75
Product B      5            2                  0.4
Product C      2            1                  0.5
```

---

I want to get the `Return Rate` based on `items` from the example table above. 
Therefore, I want to use a `count` on `Sales_Monetary` and `Returns_Monetary`. 
However, when I do this the Products with `0` returns are counted as well. 
In order to solve this issue I put `WHERE Returns_Monetary > 0`. 
Unfortunately, with this condition the `Sales_Monetary` are also not counted.

```
Select 
Product, 
count(Sales_Monetary) AS Sold_Items
count(Returns_Monetary) AS Returned_Items,
count(Returns_Monetary) / count(Sales_Monetary) AS Return_Rate_Items
FROM Sales
WHERE Returns_Monetary > 0
GROUP BY 1;
```

What do I need to change in my query to make it work?

Comment: sqlfiddle isn't answering.

Comment: `COUNT()` counts non-null values, incl. 0.

Comment: Why VARCHAR to store numerical data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I do this the Products with 0 returns are counted as well.

Here is one way to only count in `Returns_Monetary` that are greater than 0:

```
select 
    Product, 
    count(Sales_Monetary) AS Sold_Items
    sum(Returns_Monetary > 0) AS Returned_Items,
    sum(Returns_Monetary > 0) / count(Sales_Monetary) AS Return_Rate_Items
from Sales
group by 1;
```

`sum(Returns_Monetary > 0)` increases by 1 for every `Returns_Monetary` that is greater than 0.

Comment: . . The last expression can be simplified to `avg(Returns_Monetary > 0) `.